# Conditional RxJS Stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
resource1$ = hash1$.map( (renew: boolean) => renew ? http1$ : Observable.empty() );
resource2$ = hash2$.map( (renew: boolean) => renew ? http2$ : Observable.empty() );

sync$ = Observable.forkJoin(resource1$, resource2$);

sync$.subscribe( () => console.log('Sync done!), (err) => console.log('Sync failed!') );
```

Hello,
I have multiple resources to sync from an API when my application start.
I want to sync them in parallel and check if it's needed to sync them using a HEAD request before and compare X-HASH header with an old stored.

So hash1$ do a HEAD request, compare hashes and return true or false.

I'm stuck because, if resource1$ return Observable.empty, sync$ cancel all streams... And i don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to emit at least one item and complete. If you use `Observable.empty()` you're sending just the `complete` notification so that's why `forkJoin` never emits.

You can do for example:

```
resource1$ = hash1$.map((renew: boolean) => renew ? http1$ : Observable.of(false));
resource2$ = hash2$.map((renew: boolean) => renew ? http2$ : Observable.of(false));

sync$ = Observable.forkJoin(resource1$, resource2$)
  .filter(results => results[0] && results[1]); // Or whatever condition you want
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. It doesn't fail now. But i needed to use .flatMap operator in place of .map

`hash1$.flatMap((renew: boolean) => renew ? http1$ : Observable.of(false));`

Could it be because http1$ is an Observable.fromPromise ?

Comment: This depends on how you want to use `sync$` later.